# How to release a tree structure in xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, chess

I have made a tree structure using c and used it for storing some moves of a chess game.
my structure is

```
struct node{
        NSString *comment;
        NSString *move;
        struct node *variationLink;
        struct node *nextLink;
        struct node *goBack;
    };
```

i create node using malloc.When the game is changed or unloaded i want to release the tree is there any way to do it in dalloc or i have to make a function to reach each node and free it?

Comment: What about using free() to release them? You may want to do so in their parent's dealloc function, or somewhere else...

Comment: yeah i mentioned that but for that i will have to go from node to node

Comment: or you could call it recursively, if you control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function that recursively frees the structure, something like:

```
void free_nodes(struct node *n)
{
    if (n != NULL)
    {
        free_nodes(n->nextLink);
        free_nodes(n->variationLink);
        [n->comment release];
        [n->move release];
        free(n);
    }
}
```

and then just call that from within your `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    free_nodes(_root_node);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Other comments:

- You'll want a link back to the mainline of a variation, which is equivalent to the `goBack` pointer, but for variations.  This will allow you to transverse back to the mainline of any node, as at the moment there is no way of performing full transversal of your  tree.
- I would rename `goBack` to `prev`, `nextLink` to `next` and `variationLink` to `variation`, but that's up to you really.
- You need to store the move using an internal format, not as an `NSString`.  The strings should only be generated during display (in the view's draw method).  This allows you to actually use the move data rather than having to parse the string again (very expensive) and doing the string conversion only during display allows you to change how the move string is generated based on user preferences (short algebraic notation, long algebraic notation, co-ordinate notation, using piece character fonts rather than letters, etc.).

**Edit after question from OP**: In order to allow your tree to store multiple variations you need to create doubly-linked list of variations.  Therefore the node will be part of two doubly-linked lists.  Writing this in C++ will help, but I'll show it in C, if that's what you are using:

```
typedef struct node
{
    Move move;    // Holds the move (this can be done using a 32-bit unsigned integer).
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *variation;
    struct node *mainline;
    NSString *comment;
} Node;
```

Here the `mainline` link points to the previous variation, which is `NULL` if this is the mainline move.

The moves 1.e4 e5 (1...Nf6 a4) (1...Nc6 b4) 2.Nc3 would be held using a tree like this (if links are not shown on a node then they are `NULL`):

[image]

I am using this approach in a chess program I am developing and it's working very well. To re-iterate; I separate the data (this node) from the presentation (the string containing the move text which is displayed in the UI).  The generated move strings should be held in a different way altogether; perhaps Core Text, but I am using a custom method.

Comment: [n->comment release];  [n->move release]; are they needed? becoz i never called alloc on comment and move i just called malloc(sizeof(struct node)) ?

Comment: And Thanku for the free function

Comment: For those `NSString` objects to be initialized and retained correctly you must use something like `n->comment = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:c_string]];`, so yes they will need to be released to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @trojanefoe  hi my structure deals only with single variation what changes i can do to deal with multiple  variations?

Answer (score 2):

Implement destructor for node.

Use `free()` for main node if all nodes inside node are just links.

Comment: ... which results in a memory leak.